# tcl how to redefine "set" command

Tags: set, tcl, proc

I am new comming of tcl.
How to use tcl to imitate "set" command?

I try to build like below cold, but below code with error: unknown command name:

```
proc my_set {varName {value ""}} {
  uplevel 0 [set $varName $value]
}
my_set a "123"
my_set b(a) "good"

puts $a; #expected: 123
puts $b(a); #expected: good
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `my_set` proc, the script `set $varname $value` is called, and then its *result* is passed as an argument to the `uplevel` command, which will try to run that result as a script.

To have it do what you want:

```
proc my_set {varname {value ""}} {
    uplevel 1 [list set $varname $value]
}
```

or

```
proc my_set {varname {value ""}} {
    upvar 1 $varname target
    set target $value
}
```

or

```
proc my_set {varname {value ""}} {
    tailcall set $varname $value
}
```

The first (using `uplevel`) constructs the command to run in the caller's frame (the `1` argument) as a list, and then `uplevel` runs that list as a command 1 frame up the stack.

The second aliases the local variable `target` in the `my_set` proc to the variable whose name is in the `varname` variable, `1` level up the stack.  So setting the `target` variable within the `my_set` proc also sets the variable called `$varname` in the caller's frame.

The third (using `tailcall`) replaces the callframe of the `my_set` with the command `set`, which is then executing as if it was called from the parent frame.

Of the three, I would probably pick the second (using `upvar`) because there is less potential for nasty surprises waiting in your future (`uplevel` is essentially `eval` - incautious use can open remote code execution vulnerabilities), and, unless you like obscure constructions for their own sake, the `tailcall` implementation is probably just too weird.

Comment: Using `upvar` to make a link and then a local `set` call is definitely the recommended approach if possible. It's simply so much easier to get right.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

Level 0 is the current proc. To set the value in the caller's stackframe use `uplevel 1`. Since that's the default, a plain `uplevel`

Second, you want to give the uplevel command a *script*. You don't want to actually execute the set command. Typically, you'll create a **list** of the script.

```
uplevel [list set $myvar $myvalue]
```